# Generic item getter for a Swift dictionary

Tags: swift, generics, swift2

Say I have a `Dictionary<String, String>` for which I'd like to have a convenient getters for types that implement [StringLiteralConvertible](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_StringLiteralConvertible_Protocol/index.html).

```
let items = ["Key 1": "Value 1", "Key 2": "Value 2"]

func get<T: StringLiteralConvertible>(key: String, _ defaultValue: T) -> T {
    if let value = items[key] {
        return T(stringLiteral: value)  // BUG
    }

    return defaultValue
}
```

But what to put on the line marked with BUG comment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That line was actually right, but the line above should be more specific as to what type value will be. Try:

```
func get<T: StringLiteralConvertible>(key: String, _ defaultValue: T) -> T {
    if let value = items[key] as? T.StringLiteralType {
        return T(stringLiteral: value)
    }

    return defaultValue
}
```

PS: you probably also will want to pass `items` as parameter